# WSS 2.0 - Creating SPSite with a user token

Tags: sharepoint

I am developing an application that uploads documents to sharepoint document library using the object model. My application runs as a windows service under the LocalSystem user. Here, while uploading I need to set the context to another user. I have the user name with me. In MOSS 2007 I have an option to specify the user token while initializing a SPSite object. I am looking out for a similar stuff for WSS 2.0 but couldn't find one.

How can I set the user context for WSS 2.0? Please help.

Thanks,
Jagannath

Answer (score 2):

This feature was first introduced in the WSS 3.0 object model. There is no similar feature in WSS 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** There is bound to be an easier way but this is a nice reusable class and I use it extensively for just this type of operation (but not with the SP OM, at least not yet).

You would have to write a seperate piece of .Net code (some umanaged calls too) to perform impersonation of your user then call the SP object model whilst impersonating that user.  You can then restore the user account afterwards:

### VB Sample

```
Public Class UserImpersonation

    Private Declare Auto Function LogonUser Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal lpszUsername As [String], _
        ByVal lpszDomain As [String], ByVal lpszPassword As [String], _
        ByVal dwLogonType As Integer, ByVal dwLogonProvider As Integer, _
        ByRef phToken As IntPtr) As Boolean

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function FormatMessage(ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByRef lpSource As IntPtr, _
        ByVal dwMessageId As Integer, ByVal dwLanguageId As Integer, ByRef lpBuffer As [String], _
        ByVal nSize As Integer, ByRef Arguments As IntPtr) As Integer

    End Function

    Private Declare Auto Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal handle As IntPtr) As Boolean

    Private Declare Auto Function DuplicateToken Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal ExistingTokenHandle As IntPtr, _
            ByVal SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL As Integer, _
            ByRef DuplicateTokenHandle As IntPtr) As Boolean

    <PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name:="FullTrust")> _
    Public Shared Function ImpersonateUser(ByVal strDomain As String, ByVal strUserid As String, ByVal strPassword As String) As WindowsImpersonationContext

        Dim tokenHandle As New IntPtr(0)
        Dim dupeTokenHandle As New IntPtr(0)

        Try
            ' Get the user token for the specified user, domain, and password using the 
            ' unmanaged LogonUser method.  
            ' The local machine name can be used for the domain name to impersonate a user on this machine.

            Const LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT As Integer = 0
            'This parameter causes LogonUser to create a primary token.
            Const LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE As Integer = 2

            tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero

            ' Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token.
            Dim returnValue As Boolean = LogonUser(strUserid, strDomain, strPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, tokenHandle)

            If returnValue = False Then
                Dim ret As Integer = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
                Throw New System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret)
            Else
                ' Use the token handle returned by LogonUser.
                Dim newId As New WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle)
                Dim ImpersonatedUser As WindowsImpersonationContext = newId.Impersonate()

                Return ImpersonatedUser
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("UserImpersonation.impersonateUser Exception Occurred: " + ex.Message)

            Return Nothing
        End Try

        ' Free the tokens.
        If Not System.IntPtr.op_Equality(tokenHandle, IntPtr.Zero) Then
            CloseHandle(tokenHandle)
        End If
    End Function


    Public Shared Function UndoImpersonate(ByVal WIC As WindowsImpersonationContext) As Boolean
        Try
            ' Stop impersonating the user.
            WIC.Undo()

            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(("Exception occurred. " + ex.Message))

            Return False
        End Try

    End Function
End Class
```